# Call forwarding

Tags: android, phone-call

I would like to forward all calls to my number on to the new predefined number 
automatically. Is it possible to forward incoming call ?

Probably it is possible for Froyo at least. I found application called Easy Call Forwarding.
http://www.appstorehq.com/easycallforwarding-android-189596/app
But many people reckon it doesn't work actually.

We can notice forwarded call by `onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged()` from `PhoneStateListener` but
I have no idea how to set forwarding mode.

Comment: Mr Bogus : have you succeeded to forward a call ?
Mr Bill_the_Lizard : I hope this is possible, am I right ?

Answer (score 11):

I explored on the net and got the answer to my question that how one can forward a call programmatically. Add these lines of code and one will be able to achieve it.

```
String callForwardString = "**21*1234567890#";    
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // ACTION_CALL                               
Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#"); 
intentCallForward.setData(uri2);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```

Here 1234567890 represents the phone number. Add the approriate phone number as you wish here. One can dial ##21# to deactivate the service.

Comment: What error are you getting? I have tested this and it works for me. Also this works for gsm numbers only.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_DIAL will take you to the dial screen and Intent.ACTION_CALL will call the number put in setData() and thus will directly dial number **21*your_number#. This will put your phone into call forwarding mode automatically provided "your_number" is right.

Comment: Can anyone tell, where I need to add this piece of code , in the program. Is this a one time setting? will this code works even when the phone is put in flight mode?  Thanks Ganesan S

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
String prefix = "#31#";          
prefix = Uri.encode(prefix);  
intent.setData( Uri.parse("tel:"+prefix+"123456"));  
startActivity(intent);
```