# android call forwarding

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465707/call-forwarding)

how can i implement call forwarding in an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call forwarding is handled by the service provider and can't be done by the phone itself.

Once your provider has routed a call to your phone, it is not possible to 'tell' the provider programatically to re-route it elsewhere. This is not a limitation of Android, it's simply how phone networking works.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with BroadcastReceiver for "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" to block calls, but in general there doesn't seem to be any way to do call forwarding programmatically.