# android Call Forwarding programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to forward any calls received to another predefined phone number. I have searched forums and found some contradictory answers. so i m confused.

First I looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735711 which suggests that it is not possible through android.
But another post has some solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132536/1089856

I tried this code from second post, but i m getting the following error message: "Call Forwarding connection problem or Invalid MMI Code."

```
String callForwardString = "**21*5556#";   
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");
intentCallForward.setData(uri2);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```

Where 5556 is the number of emulator (for testing) where i want to forward call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i think you need to try it on the device better than the emulator.
You are using DTMF codes, so i think you need network (on the actual device) rather than on the emulator.

Dial the same code "**21*5556#" on your emulator and check. It does not work either! Replace the 5556 with the phone number you want to forward the call to and then try it on phone.

Meaning, the DTMF codes would work only on mobiles not on emulators or tablets without SIM support.

**EDIT:**
you can find different call forwarding codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding#Keypad_codes).

Comment: How can we know different forwarding codes programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "#" from **Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");**
if that do not work then try just ***21*number#**