# How can I forward a call from my friend to other my friends programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I am having a problem with my app

Logic App:

"A" call me . but i dont want to listen. i want it auto forward  this call to "B" ( A will call B).

How i do it? Any one please help me.

Comment: You can NOT. Your ISP may have ability to do this.

Comment: Thanks ! Have you had any suggestion for me ?

Comment: This is impossible, so i don't have any idea for you about this. No way :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447556/android-call-forwarding-programatically