# Can my activity receive the result of sending an MMI?

Tags: android

I can send MMIs using the approach described in e.g. [Call forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465707/call-forwarding). After the MMI is sent, there is usually a reply such as "Call forward successfully activated" or some-such.

- Is it possible for the activity which started the intent to access this reply (especially for MMIs which query status messages such as "Is call forward on?") ?
- Is it possible for my activity to prevent the system displaying the reply to the user directly? I mean this in the sense of "Not bother the user unnecessarily" rather than "stealthily doing things behind the user's back"; i.e. I don't care if the UI displays status icons etc, I just don't want the user having to confirm a large message box each time.
- If not normally, how about on a root-ed phone?

In case this is MMI dependent, I'm mainly interested in MMIs that set, query, or cancel call-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't necessarily block the popup, but for example in my app, you can send an sms to enable call forwarding, so you could run the mmi code (call `startActivity` from a broadcast receiver), and set an alarm to start the home screen about 10 seconds later. That wouldn't remove the popup, but it wouldn't be quite as annoying that way, I don't think.

If it really is important and you still care, you could break down the settings application using [dex2jar](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=4&gs_id=3z&xhr=t&q=dex2jar&qe=ZGV4Mg&qesig=P10rSDaeLBASccbd-bwM1A&pkc=AFgZ2tng2mI2W0QftI6fNuuIOa7_5G4ulvZ20EQ3Y3V-VW9aaDCefn6G0Y67q_qGLpL3WjN5ZrnCfsXMP4fVsFBd0YtdoJi70g&pq=jd-gui&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=dex2&aq=0p&aqi=p-p2g2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4a9ec763a1c8bfb0&biw=1646&bih=905) and then use [A java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to read the jar file.

If anybody finds out the answer to this question, I would also be interested. I may do the work myself sometime, but I just don't care enough right now or have the time.