# How to divert phone calls in android to another phone number

Tags: android

I want to write an application which be able to divert calls to another number, I know it can be done on phones by it self, but I want to only direct specific number to another number.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465707/call-forwarding