# Android Incoming Call not forwarding to other phone number programatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to forward incoming call to other number once after phone receives call. The following is my written code to forward call. It is entering into this `onRecieve` but call is not forwarding. Please help me.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            String callForwardString = "**21*9876543210#";    
            Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // ACTION_CALL                               
            Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#"); 
            intentCallForward.setData(uri2);  
            intentCallForward.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intentCallForward); 
        }

    },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465707/call-forwarding , maybe it helps

Comment: In the given link one answer is same as i did but it is not working. And the other answer they provided is to make a new call not to forward a call.

Comment: and have You read this? http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/01/how-to-forward-incoming-call-in-android.html  ? it´s a little bit different than Yours...

Comment: I tried that, even it is not working,I have added that code in onCallStateChanged method. Is that the place to add or in any other method?.

Comment: can You post Your manifest? Maybe here is a problem..

Comment: I added the following permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> and this is my reciever    <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: and the permission is also placed inside the manifest tag? I am asking because some poeple missing this and place the permission for example under the application tag

Comment: And maybe You have to declare what to do at which state. That I am missing in Your code.You are starting directly at callStateChanged, but don´t define what to do in which state...